# How do I associate an Ajax error result with the original request?

Tags: ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am sending data to the server in small bursts using the jQuery `ajax` function.  Each chunk of data is a simple key-value map (the `data` property passed to the `ajax` function).

If a request fails, how can my error event handler identify *which* specific set of data failed to be uploaded?

The function signature of the jQuery error handler is:

```
error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

Neither `textStatus` or `errorThrown` seem useful to identify the failed set of data, and the XHR doesn't seem to offer that capability either.

Simply put, if a request fails, I want to be able to get the `id` property of the `data` that I passed to the `ajax` function.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [`this`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#callback-functions)... From the docs - pay attention to the highlighted section:

> The `beforeSend`, `error`, `dataFilter`, `success` and `complete` options all take callback functions that are invoked at the appropriate times. The `this` object for all of them will be the object in the `context` property passed to `$.ajax` in the settings; **if that was not specified it will be a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.**

So, in the `error()` callback (also `success` and `complete`, etc), `this` will be the object passed to `$.ajax()` - unless you are using the `context` parameter to change it.

As a note, the `data` param passed into `$.ajax()` will be converted to a serialized string for a GET or POST request

The other option, is to just make sure your `error()` callback has access to the variable in the same scope:

```
 (function() { 
   // create a scope for us to store the data:
   var data = {id: 1};
   $.ajax({
      url: '/something-to-genereate-error',
      data: data,
      error: function() {
        console.log(this, data);
      }
   });
 })(); // call the function immediatey
```

[See this fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/Pk8Aa/) - Note that the `data` inside of `this` is `"id=1"` wereas the `data` we held a copy of is still `{id:1}`

Also - Note that the closure here (`(function() { .... })()`) Is pretty much unnecessary, it is just showing a way to store the `data` variable before passing it into `$.ajax()` and the using it in the callback.  Most likely this ajax call already lies within a function where you could do this.

Comment: Does this only work when you call .ajax() directly? I can't get it work but I'm using .getJSON()

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found it (based on my previous answer and the one from gnarf,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "not-found",        
    context: {id: 123, name: "hello world"},        
    error: function(){  
        console.debug($(this)); //only works in chrome                    
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  Which property of XHR contains the request parameters?

Comment: Interesting. It seems none does, you could however try to add a header using these events http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events

Comment: -1 for editing your answer to effectively duplicate mine... Only your answer provides no explanation of how to actually obtain the information the OP is asking for.

Comment: You are right (tho I posted the docs first), I just wanted to get some code that actually worked because it wasn't the way I first tought about it and got kicked out of the office as I was redacting the post. I should delete this answer but first copy the code to yours, it has an important difference, that you don't need the closure, $.ajax does it for you.